# ¿Qué es el calendarizador en una BDD?

Tags: base-de-datos

mientras buscaba información sobre el funcionamiento de las Bases de Datos Distribuidas me encuentro con un termino en wikipedia que repiten varias veces pero en ningún momento explican que es, este es:

> **calendarizador**

Lo mencionan durante la detección de bloqueos, transparencia de ubicación, transparencia de duplicado, y durante el funcionamiento del Manejador de transacciones distribuidas (DTM) (donde mas me interesa saber que función tiene), donde se menciona:

> "El manejador recibe solicitudes de procesamiento de transacciones y
> las traduce en acciones para el calendarizador"

¿Acaso el calendarizador es una pila de transacciones que maneja el DTM?¿O establece un tiempo(de un calendario) donde las transacciones deben ser realizadas? Tras buscar sobre la palabra no conseguí mucho y no se como debería buscarla en ingles.

¡Muchas gracias de ante mano!

*Pd: Espero que sea esta la comunidad de stackexchange indicada para preguntar sobre el tema, si no es el caso por favor díganme el sitio correcto.*

Comment: Mas que una pila, sería una cola, aunque bien podría ser simplemente un lote. En inglés busca *scheduler*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En inglés, el término es **scheduler**. Y un término más preciso, en lugar de "calendarizador", sería ***planificador***.

Traduzco parte del contenido de la sección *Distributed Timestamp Concurrency Control* ("Control de concurrencia distribuido de marcas de tiempo") de [esta página](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/distributed_dbms/distributed_dbms_controlling_concurrency.htm) (énfasis mío):

> (...) *Para implementar los algoritmos de ordenación de marcas de tiempo, cada sitio tiene un **planificador** que *mantiene una cola separada para cada gestor de transacciones*. Durante la transacción, un gestor (manejador) de transacciones envía una solicitud de bloqueo al planificador del sitio. El planificador pone la solicitud en la cola correspondiente en orden creciente de marca de tiempo. Las solicitudes se procesan desde el frente de las colas en el orden de sus marcas de tiempo, es decir, la más antigua primero.*

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Es justo lo que buscaba.

Answer (score 1):

"**Calendarizar**" es un verbo resultante de un anglicismo del inglés *calendarize*. No es un término reconocido por la Real Academia Española (consultado en la vigesimosegunda edición).

Oxford Languages define *calendarize* como "**programar, asignar o registrar (algo) mes a mes**".

**Ejemplo de uso**: "Normalmente, *calendarizaremos* el estado de resultados completo.".

Por lo tanto, un calendarizador se define como un componente que esté destinado a realizar un proceso de calendarización.

Answer (score 0):

Es un conjunto de múltiples bases de datos lógicamente relacionadas las cuales se encuentran distribuidas en diferentes espacios lógicos y geográficos (pej. un servidor corriendo 2 máquinas virtuales) e interconectados por una red de comunicaciones. Dichas BDD tienen la capacidad de realizar procesamientos autónomos, estos permiten realizar operaciones locales o distribuidas